# How to drop designate row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I´m new to python, sorry for any mistakes I make, I hope you can understand me.

I have a problem quit like dropping duplicate row.But here i view 1,2 the same as 2,1.And there isn't any actually duplicate items in the pandas dataframe. For example,i have df as

```
first second
1     2
2     1
2     4
4     2
```

and i need df eventually become:

```
first second
1     2
2     4
```

How to tackle this problem .
thanks in advance.

### update

Here is another problem,the dataframe have 1860000 rows,so when using this method will raise memory error. Is there some ways to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `sorted` and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df.apply(sorted, axis=1))
   first  second
0      1       2
1      1       2
2      2       4
3      2       4

df = df.apply(sorted, axis=1).drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   first  second
0      1       2
2      2       4
```

Comment: Here is another problem,the dataframe have 1860000 rows,so when using  this method will raise memory error. Is there some ways to tackle this?